# Passing an object variable vs. passing an object literal to a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, literals

In TypeScript, if I define an interface `MyInterface` such as:

```
interface MyInterface {
  a ?: string;
}
```

And if I define a function `myFunction` that only accepts a parameter of type `MyInterface` such as:

```
function myFunction(parameter: MyInterface) {
  console.log("hello!")
}
```

If I define an object `myObject`

```
let myObject = {
  a: "lol",
  b: "hi"
}
```

And call `myFunction` with `myObject` as a parameter `myFunction(myObject)` TypeScript gives no errors.

But if I call `myFunction` with an object literal as a parameter with the same data as `myObject`

`myFunction({a: "lol", b: "hi"})` TypeScript gives the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ a: string; b: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyInterface'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'MyInterface'.(2345)
```

Why doesn't this error appear when I call `myFunction` with the object variable ?

Comment: Here where you can get an answer to your issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed !

Comment: @НиколайГольцев You should summarize that content and make it the answer to this question :)